# create dict from lists using key list again

Tags: python

I have two list

```
listA = (1,2,3,4)
listB = (A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D)
```

I want to build a dictionary reusing `listA` as the key to all values in `listB`

```
dict = {1:A,2:B,3:C,4:D,1:A,2:B,3:C,4:D,1:A,2:B,3:C,4:D,1:A,2:B,3:C,4:D,1:A,2:B,3:C,4:D}
```

I am not able to use `itertools` I also have to take in to consideration that some of my values are empty so I am trying to build the `dict` like this

```
def create_dict(keys,values):
  return dict(zip(keys, values + [None] * (len(keys) - len(values))))
```

Which works but only for length of the keys.

Comment: Python dict cannot have two equal keys, as in your example.

Comment: Keys in a dictionary must be unique, so your result isn't possible

Comment: What do you hope to achieve from a dictionary that appears to map the exact same keys to the exact same values multiple times?

Comment: What do you mean by "some of my values are empty"? This question is very unclear.

Comment: Yes i see my error now, i will need to make a next of dictionaries

Comment: John i think it is clear to say that some of the values in my list have no value the list is taken from a table, and some of those cells do not have a value in them, but they should still map to a the right key

Comment: It isn't clear based on what you have written (which is the only thing we have to go on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dict you want to generate is not possible - it contains multiple keys that are the same key, and that is not allowed in dicts.

You could have a single key pointing to a list of values:

```
import collections
import itertools

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(itertools.cycle(listA), listB):
    d[k].append(v)
```

that would generate a dict like this:

```
{
    1: [A, A, A, A],
    2: [B, B, B, B],
    3: [C, C, C, C],
    4: [D, D, D, D],
}
```

Comment: thank you, that is really what i want as `listA` is column headers and `listB` is the cell values

Comment: @pyth0nBen sounds very much like a *dataframe*. Perhaps you might find [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) helpful.